# Automated creation of slice ranges for numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have read a few answers elaborating how should one pass multiple slices as indices to an numpy array, to select multiple, non-adjacent ranges in the array.
What I cannot figure out is how to automate slice creation, and pass this list of slices as indices to the numpy array of interest.
For instance, `x` is an array of shape *(100,)* and `ind` is a list of indices (monotonically increasing). What I wish to do looks like the following:

```
slices = [ind[i]:ind[i+1] for i in chosen]
```

where `chosen` is a list which lists the indices of specific values in `ind`. For instance,

```
>>> ind
array([10, 20, 29, 38, 46, 54, 66, 72, 85, 91], dtype=int64)
>>> chosen
array([0, 1, 2, 5, 7], dtype=int64)
```

So `ind[chosen[3]]:ind[chosen[3]+1] = 54:66`. I hope the idea is clear.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: In your case do you want the range from 54 to 66 as an np array?

Comment: @Finn No, see, I need all such slices specified by`slices` as one single np array.

Comment: Share expected output for given sample? Think this should do it - `np.hstack(np.split(ind, chosen)[1:-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I am not sure about the start and the end of your slices. For example 20 is the end of the first and the start of the second, but this fits your example.

```
slices = [list(range(ind[chosen[i]],ind[chosen[i]+1]+1)) for i in range(len(chosen))]
print(slices)

[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38], [54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66], [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear as to what you want.  Finn's answer may work for you.  If you want to use slice to index into an array you need it as a list, not a list of lists.

```
slices = []
for i in chosen:
    slices.extend( [ x for x in range( ind[i], ind[i+1] ) ] )

print( slices )
# [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,     
#  29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 
#  64, 65, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84]

import numpy as np

x = np.arange( 100,200 )

print( x[ slices ] )
# array([110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122,
#        123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135,
#        136, 137, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164,
#        165, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183,
#        184])
```

OR

```
slices = [ slice( ind[i], ind[i+1] ) for i in chosen ]
print(slices)
# [slice(10, 20, None), slice(20, 29, None), slice(29, 38, None), 
# slice(54, 66, None), slice(72, 85, None)]

result = x [ np.r_[ tuple(slices) ]]

# [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124,     
#  125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 154, 155,    
#  156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 
#  177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184]
```